# removeField in adminhtml

Tags: adminhtml, event-observer, adminform

In the customer/edit page (adminhtml) I set up some custom fields, they appear by default under information account tab.

I created an observer (event is `adminhtml_block_html_before`), and I need to remove the fields from the form. I see there is a `removeField` method I could use, but I cannot find any explanation on how to do it from the observer.

Answer (score 3):

you can try this

```
$this->getForm()->getElement('content_fieldset')->removeField('content_heading');
```

or this

```
// Remove the elementId from the form
$this->getForm()->removeField('password_fieldset');
// Remove the fieldset
$this->getForm()->getElements()->remove('password_fieldset');
```

or you can just disabled it

```
$event = $observer->getEvent();
$form = $event->getForm();    
$form->getElement('is_active')->setData('disabled', true);
```

Comment: Hi @andhi Irawan, Could you please explain how to do the same in Magento 2.0

Comment: Hi @VenuJoginpally, do you mean this? http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/howdoi/customize_product.html

Answer (score 3):

@andhi Irawan you can achieve same thing in Magento 2 using below code.

**create events.xml on path Namespace\ModuleName\etc\adminhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
   <event name="adminhtml_block_html_before">
       <observer name="namespace_moodulename_observer_hidefields" instance="Namespace\ModuleName\Observer\HideFields" />
   </event>
</config>
```

**Create Observer file (Hidefields.php) on path Namespace\ModuleName\Observer**

 you can change the file name as per your choice.

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\ModuleName\Observer;

class HideFields implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_request;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
    ){
        $this->_request = $request;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $acionName = $this->_request->getFullActionName();

        $ruleId = $this->_request->getParam('entity_id');
        // $actionName is your admin edit form action
        if($acionName === 'pricerules_lrpricerules_edit')
        {
            $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();
            if (!isset($block))
                return $this;

            if ($block->getType() == 'Namespace\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Lrpricerules\Edit\Tab\Main') 
            {
                $form = $block->getForm();
                $filedArray = array();
                // base_fieldset is the fieldset id defined in your form
                $fieldset = $form->getElement('base_fieldset');
                if($ruleId)
                {
                    // fields ids array to remove from form
                    $filedArray = array('field1','field2');


                    if(!empty($filedArray))
                    {
                        foreach($filedArray as $fieldId)
                        {
                           $fieldset->removeField($fieldId);
                        }   
                    }
                }
            }
        }   

        return $this;
    }
}
```